# How to find out if ListView has scrolled to top Most position?

Tags: android

I have a ListView, first its scrolled down, now when we scroll up,it reach top most point. I want to detect that .Is there any way?I am developing application with api level 8.Pls help..

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**edit**

See comments below as to why, especially on different API versions (esp later ones), this isn't a foolproof way to see if you're list is at the top (padding etc). However, it does give you a start for a solution on devices below API 14:

```
private boolean listIsAtTop()   {   
    if(listView.getChildCount() == 0) return true;
    return listView.getChildAt(0).getTop() == 0;
}
```

As far as my implementation years ago - this worked perfectly at the time.

Comment: This doesn't always return 0 when at the top of a list for me

Comment: (You can added ...getTop() > 0 || ...getTop() < getChildAt(0).getHeight() or similar if you need to check if the top item is visible)

Comment: this doesnt really work for me, while scrolling it will randomly return 0 for getTop of the 0 index child even if the list isnt at the top

Comment: It will return the top of the first visible child i think.

Comment: I'm sorry but this solution is not really correct because it doesn't take in account eventual padding that the first element can have.

Comment: This only tells if the first list element is visible, but such first element might still not be totally scrolled up.

Answer (score 21):

I know this question is old, but it shows up top in Google search results. There is a new method introduced in API level 14 that gives exactly what we needed:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#canScrollVertically%28int%29

<s>For older platforms one can use similar static methods of `ViewCompat` in the v4 support library.</s> See edit below.

Unlike Graeme's method, this method is immune of problems caused by the internal view reuse of `ListView` and/or header offset.

**Edit: final solution**

I've found a method in the source code of [SwipeRefreshLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html) that handles this. It can be rewritten as:

```
public boolean canScrollUp(View view) {
  if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 14) {
    if (view instanceof AbsListView) {
      final AbsListView absListView = (AbsListView) view;
      return absListView.getChildCount() > 0
          && (absListView.getFirstVisiblePosition() > 0 || absListView
              .getChildAt(0).getTop() < absListView.getPaddingTop());
    } else {
      return view.getScrollY() > 0;
    }
  } else {
    return ViewCompat.canScrollVertically(view, -1);
  }
}
```

You may need to add custom logic if the passed-in view is a custom view.

Comment: Be aware that the ViewCompat methods for canScrollVertically and canScrollHorizontally always return false on platform levels below ICS. The implementation sets the those methods to return false unless overridden and only the impl for ICS overrides the methods.

Comment: @lillicoder You're right. We can't use the implementations on older platforms. I've edited the answer to make it work for all platforms.

Answer (score 13):

My friends, combining **Graeme**'s answer with the onScroll method...

```
listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        if(firstVisibleItem == 0 && listIsAtTop()){
            swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(true);
        }else{
            swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
});


private boolean listIsAtTop()   {
    if(listView.getChildCount() == 0) return true;
    return listView.getChildAt(0).getTop() == 0;
}
```

Comment: thumbs up for mentioning swipeRefreshLayout. specifically what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to check what is the first visible position then applying Graeme's solution to see if the first visible listview item is at the top position.

Something like 
lv.getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0 && (lv.getChildCount() == 0 || lv.getChildAt(0).getTop() == 0)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [OnScrollListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html) to be notified the position 0 is now visible. Use the `onScroll`method.

Comment: my list item is really big, so i cant compare to see if firstVisibleItem is 0, as the item covers half the screen. If the item is only half visible (in the top). then also firstVisibleItem  is 0, which is not the top most of listView.

Comment: The asker wants to know about the top most point not when the top item is reached. This will still trigger if on the first item but not at the top most point

Answer (score 1):

This question is old but I have a solution that works perfectly and it is possible that works for someone looking for a solution.

```
int limitRowsBDshow = 10; //size limit your list
listViewMessages.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        int counter = 1;
        int currentScrollState;
        int currentFirstVisibleItem;
        int currentVisibleItemCount;
        int currentTotalItemCount;


        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            this.currentScrollState = scrollState;
            this.isScrollCompleted();
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

            this.currentFirstVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem;
            this.currentVisibleItemCount = visibleItemCount;
            this.currentTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
        }

        private void isScrollCompleted() {
            if (this.currentVisibleItemCount > 0 && this.currentScrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                /*** detect if there's been a scroll which has completed ***/

                counter++;
                if (currentFirstVisibleItem == 0 && currentTotalItemCount > limitRowsBDshow - 1) {
                     linearLay20msgMas.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

This code is found a time ago (here StackOverflow). But I can not find this to mention

Answer (score 0):

Graeme's answer is close but is missing something that user2036198 added, a check for getFirstVisiblePosition(). getChildAt(0) doesn't return the very first view for the very first item in the list. AbsListView implementations don't make a single view for every position and keep them all in memory. Instead, view recycling takes effect to limit the number of views instantiated at any one time.

The fix is pretty simple:

```
public boolean canScrollVertically(AbsListView view) {
    boolean canScroll = false;

    if (view != null && view.getChildCount() > 0) {
        // First item can be partially visible, top must be 0 for the item
        canScroll = view.getFirstVisiblePosition() != 0 || view.getChildAt(0).getTop() != 0;
    }

    return canScroll;
}
```

For best results on ICS or higher, always use ViewCompat from the v4 support library or View.canScrollVertically(). Use the above method on lower API levels as ViewCompat always returns false for canScrollVertically() and canScrollHorizontally() below ICS.

Answer (score 0):

If you can extends ListView directly, then you can use the protected method called "computeVerticalScrollOffset()" inside the override method "onScrollChanged()".

With that protected method return 0, means that your ListView is now reached at top.

Code Snippet

```
        listView = new ListView(this){
        @Override
        protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
            super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);

            if( computeVerticalScrollOffset() == 0 ){
                // Reach top
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Too late but try this one it works well in RecyclerView.
-1 to check if it can scroll to top while 1 is to check if it can scroll to bottom

```
if (listView.canScrollVertically(-1))
   listView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
else
   onBackPressed();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
lstView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
                if (0 == firstVisibleItem){
                    Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "Scroll to Top ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: The asker wants to know about the top most point not when the top item is reached. This will still trigger if on the first item but not at the top most point.