# Pin layout on top of Listview

Tags: android, xml, android-listview

I need to pin the layout filtering.xml to the top of `ListView`, but this layout needs to be on the top of this list still, it should be considered as one of the items of the `ListView` and during the scrolling down should this layout hide.

I tried to use the method `addHeaderView` with this layout filtering.xml, but then it is considered really as one of the items with only one single touch listener.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question but maybe you should use *layout inflation* to remove the view when you are scrolling?

Or create 2 listviews on top of each other?

Comment: Im sorry but I tried this solution and it doesn't work. Do you have any other suggestions? I can't use 2 listviews, because I need during scrolling my listview hide the layout on the top. Layout inflation does't work too, because I need to assign many touch listeners to views in this layout and during getView it will destroy this layout.

Comment: Can't you just remove an entry from your listview during scrolling and adding that entry back when you reach the top?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318373/how-to-find-out-if-listview-has-scrolled-to-top-most-position